# what is authentication mechanism of IoT node with blockchain?

Tags: authentication, methods, model, blockchain, iot

i am doing my project on integration of IoT devices, but  here i'm facing some difficulties for the the authentication of node with blockchain, there is PKI infrastructure integrated with blockchain. but i need some purely blockchain base method, if anyone know  about any model or mechanism which is use for authentication through blockcahin please help me.

Comment: Why do you think such identification method exists? I don't think blockchain is useful for authentication aside from proving ownership of funds.

Comment: i think if we use blockchain for it it will be more secure method, what is problem or constrain if we use blockchain for authentication? according to your opinion.

Comment: you're looking at the problem backwards. What are you trying to achieve? Blockchain was designed to allow a distributed network of computers to agree on a state of the ownership and supply of a digital currency. Authentication requires a network with a central authority, which blockchain is not useful for.

Comment: Then please suggest Any other secure method for authentication of iot nodes rather PKI or blovkchain base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question very broad, there is many different blockchain types, and different signing/authentication mechanisms. Thus, there is not universal solution, works on any blockchain.
However, if you use Bitcoin-based blockchain (like BTC/NMC/EMC), you can use JSON RPC API commands **signmessage/verifymessage** to develop your IoT authentication challenge protocol. Common idea: server provide to client a random string (challenge), client sign it with signmessage, and return to server. Server runs verifymessage and make decision.

Or, you can use already matured blockchain PKI platforms, for example, see Emercoin's [emerSSL](https://emercoin.com/files/uploads/docs/EMCSSL.pdf) and [emerSSH](https://emercoin.com/en/documentation/blockchain-services/emerssh) systems.

Comment: Alright. could you please let me know is it good approach if we use Blockchain base authentication instead of PKI approach in IoT devices with the perspective of security, time and cost?

Comment: I think, using blockchain for authentication only maybe overkill. But maybe not - it depends on cost to support PKI (including admin salaries and equipment cost) vs cost to support blockchain (storage space on IoT device, and time-to-time binary upgrade). You need compute both and compare. But, definitely, blockchain-based authentication will great, if you will use several blockchain services at once. There can be PKI functional, Randpay, DNS and so on. In this case, cost of a single blockchain will be shared between services, and cost of some specific service (like PKI) will be small.

Comment: do you suggest NameCoin Based Decentralized Authentication System for authentication?